# Does anyone know of text message corpora?

Tags: corpora, resource-request, computer-aided-communication

I am looking for a large corpus of text messages. By large, I am hoping to have at least 15,000 text messages in my sample. I am fine with combining several smaller corpora into a larger corpus as I will also be adding thousands of text messages relating to the patterns of interest in my research.

**Clarification on Requirements:**

- Text messages should predominantly be in English (US/American ideally), although a mixture of Spanish (Mexican Spanish) is also good.
- The corpus can be either free or available for a reasonable fee.
- They should be text messages, as I am specifically looking for euphemisms and slang used in text messaging as well as emoticons.

Comment: It isn't exactly what you're asking for but have you considered using the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) to build a corpus of tweets?

Comment: not free, but look at this: https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2017T07

Comment: @Daniel this is in Egyptian Arabic, not English (see first bulleted requirement) in question

Answer (score 11):

I only found this corpus on the [NUS (National University of Singapore)](http://www.nus.edu.sg/) site, but luckily it has a lot of entries.

It has a [download](http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg:8080/SMSCorpus/old.jsp)<sup>1</sup>  for a corpus containing ~10,000 text messages, which was the original corpus.

But if you go to [this page](http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg:8080/SMSCorpus/history.jsp)<sup>2</sup>, there is a table listing the corpora (they range from ~10,000 to ~51,000 text messages) available for download. The top line being the most recent corpus there; you can download either in XML or SQL, or download the statistics.

I must remind you (and everyone who uses it) that *you should make sure to follow the instructions asked by the researchers*, in case you choose it.

**Update**: please see the comment below my answer.

---

<sub>**Notes**: It looks like the download site is down, instead you can download all the data from their [Github Repo](https://github.com/WING-NUS/nus-sms-corpus)</sub>

Comment: @Dan O'Day I'm one of organizers of the NUS SMS Corpus, referenced in this answer. We had a recent paper in *Language Resources and Evaluation* that describes all of the SMS corpora we found, paid or free, that are of some non-trivial scale (you can get the preprint from the corpus website, linked in the answer). Unfortunately, none of them really match your U.S. Eng/Spa (Mexican) requirements. The NUS corpus' English messages are largely from Singaporean university students, so the language you'll see used are quite a bit different than those you would see in U.S. SMS.

Comment: @majnemɪzdæn Consider accepting the answer if it solves your question. :)

Comment: @Alenanno my apologies, I vacillate only because technically this did not meet my requirements (the Singaporean English didn't work for my requirements). The reality is that there likely is not a corpus that does. [I ended up beginning to create one, but do not have enough samples yet to make it all that significant.](http://cybersecurity.cit.purduecal.edu/content/tmcorpus.html) I did upvote this answer, however - but perhaps another corpus will come to light?

Comment: @majnemɪzdæn Don't worry, there is nothing forcing you to accept, especially if you're not 100% satisfied, but I doubt there's a corpus that will, as you said.

Comment: It was recently brought to my attention that Purdue is no longer hosting the corpus I developed. Here is it on Web Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20131123115633/http://cybersecurity.cit.purduecal.edu/content/tmcorpus.html

Comment: link die http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg:8080/SMSCorpus/history.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other datasets:

- [Arruda's dataset (5171 messages)](https://www.kaggle.com/leoarruda/documents)
- [NER dataset (7398 messages)](https://www.kaggle.com/sahanr/multiclass-sms-dataset)

The NER dataset has the named entities replaced by entity types, like in `[ORGANIZATION]`, `[DATE]`, etc.   The Arruda dataset is mainly English and surprisingly emoji free.  Neither of the datasets provide much detail on how they were created.

[Google has a search engine for datasets](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/help) that is a good starting point when looking for datasets.  It covers Kaggle, the US Government, some scientific journals, as well as Statista, Data World, and other data aggregators.

Answer (score 2):

A standard tool in the search for corpora is the [CLARIN virtual language observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu). [Searching for "twitter" and setting the language facet to English](https://vlo.clarin.eu/search?q=twitter&fqType=languageCode:or&fq=languageCode:code:eng) gives *Twitter sentiment for 15 European languages* as the top result. The corpus is under a free licence.