# Corpus of Chat/IM/Text Conversations?

Tags: corpora

I was wondering if there is any conversational corpus available to the public. The ideal corpus would be one made up of AIM messages with users tagged and lots of different users.  I would imagine something like this might not be available and haven't been able to find anything for a while now.

I would guess there are some issues with privacy but I am more looking for generic chat conversations so even a corpus with a lot of privacy related things stripped would be helpful.

In case nothing like this exists I was looking for websites with large comment sections that I could crawl online (reddit, imgur, youtube) so any suggestions for that list would be welcome.

Comment: http://faculty.nps.edu/cmartell/NPSChat.htm

Comment: Awesome, I'm actually already using the python NLTK I just didn't realize this was a part of it. Thanks

Comment: do you use n-gram language model?may i talk about something that?

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [the NPS chat corpus](http://faculty.nps.edu/cmartell/NPSChat.htm) included with NLTK, also see [NUS text message corpus for text conversations.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1416/3492) You can also use [the Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com) to build a corpus of tweets as well.