# I am working on a sentiment analysis project. I am looking for user text messages on which I would be doing my analysis

Tags: analysis

I have run my model on sample data. Now I need user text messages to perform analysis on actual data. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: So you need a corpus of user text messages, right?

Comment: Yes Adel I want a corpus of user text messages

Comment: Take a look at here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/does-anyone-know-of-text-message-corpora

Comment: This is a similar question on the opendata SE: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/165/american-english-sms-text-message-corpora